# changed text and colour button with boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got few buttons question and would like to change the txt color after the value changed. ex: begin with "select" --> changes to "positive" (answer).
where should I make the loop to check if the value was changed? how?

I'm stuck on this code and any help will be good.

```js
    var answers = ['Positive', 'Negative'];
    if (typeof ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS[i].header == 'undefined') {
                $('#questionsTable tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#rowTemplate tbody", data));
                $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").text(data.inspectionResult || 'Select');
                $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").click(resultHandler.bind(data));
                updateActiveStatus(data);
                commentvisibilitymanager(data);
                    if(ARRAY_OF_QUESTIONS[i].header == 'undefined'){
                    $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").text(data.inspectionResult || 'Select').addClass(asnwers)
                } // loop check for value 
                    if (asnwers) {
                        
                    }
            }
            else {
                $('#questionsTable tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#sectionRowTemplate tbody", data));
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table frame="box" id="questionnaireHeader" width="100%'" position="fixed">
         <tr height="40px" style="background: #006b54; color:white" >
             <td width="70%" align="center" style="align:center">Question</div>
             <td width="30%" align="center" style="align:center">Result</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       <table frame="box" width="100%" id="questionsTable">
           <tbody>
               
               
           </tbody>
       </table>
    
      <!-- This hosts all HTML templates that will be used inside the JavaScript code -->
       <table class ="cls-{id} active-{active}" style="display:none;" width="100%" id="rowTemplate">
            <tr class ="bb cls-{id} active-{active}">
                <td class="active-{active}" id="{id}-question" width="70%">{question}</td>
                <td class="cls-{id} active-{active}" style="border-style:hidden; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;" width="30%">
                    <button class="buttons" step="0.01" data-clear-btn="false" style="background: #006b54; border radius: px; color:white !important ;" id="{id}-inspectionResult"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
       </table>
       
                 <div id="projectPopUp"  class="popup-window" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="popuptitle" id="details-name"></div>
                            <table id="detailsgrid">
                          <tbody></tbody>
                         </table>
                        <div>
                            <button class="smallButton" onClick="closePopup()">Close</button>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                <table style="display:none;" id="popupPersonTemplate">
                    <tr class ="bb cls-{id}">
            <td width="70%">{name}</td>
            <td width="30%">
                <button class="buttons" step="0.01" data-clear-btn="false" style="background: #006b54; color:white !important ;" id="{id}-status"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
                </table>
                
       <!--closeProjectPopup()-->
       
       <table style="display: none;" id="sectionRowTemplate">
           <tr width="100%" class="bb cls-{id}-row2 sectionheader">
               <td class="cls-{id}" colspan="3">{question}</td>
           </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: The HTML would help. Could you please add that?

Comment: For a complete answer, you should post your HTML code as well.
Anyway, for stuff like that you usually want to handle certain types of events, E.G. a button is pressed etc..

Comment: there is my html, tks

Comment: your js seems to have a syntax issue of unbalanced parenthesis. You should fix it

Answer (score 0):

its done!

```
var checkComplete = true;
            var questionResults = data.employee_results;
            for (var employee in questionResults){
                if (questionResults[employee] == ''){
                    checkComplete = false; 
                }
            }

            if (checkComplete) {
                //button 
                $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").text('Done');
            }
            else {
                $("#" + id + "-inspectionResult").text('Select');
            }

        }
        else {
            $('#questionsTable tbody').append(Utils.processTemplate("#sectionRowTemplate tbody", data));
        }
```